# trouble finding css code to change background active menu in drupal 7 bartik

Tags: css, drupal-7

When inspecting element for a menu active link background,

can't find corresponding code in styles.css to change

for sub theme of bartik in latest vs drupal 7.

Trying to change tab background of

active menu link.

```
li a.active, #main-menu-links 
background: #330033;

<div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
    <h2 class="element-invisible">Main menu</h2><ul id="main-menu-links" class="links clearfix"><li class="menu-388 first active"><a href="/" title="opening page " class="active">Home</a></li>
```

In sub theme added but hasn't worked:

```
.featured #main-menu-links li a.active {
  background: #2c2c28;

}
```

Comment: Do you have your app hosted for us to check, these kinda issues it should help

Comment: go to thelastyawn.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a subtheme, make sure that you copy the file `/themes/bartik/css/colors.css` to `/sites/all/themes/[your subtheme]/css/colors.css`, and copy the folder and its contents `/themes/bartik/color/` to `/sites/all/themes/[your subtheme]/color/`.

Your declaration should work in `[your subtheme].css` file if you remove the `.featured` selector:

```
#main-menu-links li a.active {
  background: #2c2c28;
}
```